# C# - How to detect if website was visited

Tags: c#, web, sniffer, visited

I want to make a program which detects if some website was opened/visited by the user, for example, facebook.com. It has to work regardless of the used web browser.

I thought about checking records in DNS Cache, it would work, but there is a problem - it will generate false positives. Why, because some pages contain facebook widgets. In this case, I don't need to visit fb to make facebook.com appears in my DNS cache, it will appear all the time I visit the website that contains fb widgets.

The second idea was looking for active TCP connections, but it doesn't work too.

The last idea was to sniff traffic. I made simple test in Wireshark and there is the same problem as in checking DNS cache records, more precisely false positives. Also, fb uses https protocol, so I can't see that simple their address, I have to obtain their IPs from DNS and then try to find them out in the sniffed traffic.

I have no more ideas how to solve this problem.

Comment: Whell, what you ask cannot be done, technically speaking, if a page includes a widget from facebook the user visited facebook... maybe you can add a proxy middleware like Fiddler?, then you can read the Http request and determine if the visited route matches your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about banning or tracking the IP address for facebook?
I did a nslookup for facebook.com and got:

nslookup facebook.com

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    facebook.com
Addresses:  2a03:2880:f001:1f:face:b00c:0:25de
          31.13.76.68

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would to be using the [Titanium Web Proxy](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy), and utilize the `OnRequest` event in order to track calls to certain domains (stored in the `SessionEventArgs.ProxySession.Request.Url`) property in the `OnRequest` call. You can even modify the results / requests before they go out. However, be aware that this library does overwrite your current system proxy settings.